# How to set up a new puppet master for my current running environment

Tags: puppet

I had a bad situation where my puppet master running on ec2 instance got terminated.I managed to setup a new master  server ,but now my clients are not able to  connect to the new master .I use the same vip which is configured on  route 53.Is  there a way  that  I  can direct my clients to my new master and force them to create a new client certificate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the clients' current certificates (location depends on Puppet version, configuration, and user; check the docs).  Having done so, they should issue certificate requests to the master on the next catalog run.  It sounds like the new master is reachable at the same name / location as the old, so you should not need to modify client configurations.  You will need to either turn on certificate autosigning at the new master or manually sign the new certs.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Did exactly the same steps , it worked like a charm !!